# Git LFS with branches

Tags: git, github

I have my master branch with git lfs properly working. I wanted to start a new branch for development but when I push, I get the "this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB" error.

Even after I do git track with my new branch and make sure its not in the commit, the error still persists.

How do I start a new branch and have git lfs still working?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you track a smaller file?

Comment: I get the same error even if I don't track anything. I am pretty sure its because my old commits include the large file. I have read other posts about having to remove the large file from every old commit, but I really want to find another way since that is very annoying everytime I want to start a branch.

Comment: If the file already exists in the repo you don't have many options. History will need to be rewritten. Or, if you're really lucky you can remove the file in one commit and then add it again in the next, moving it to LFS.